# Cannot rename(mv) directory created with ADB tool with owner shell from an Android app on Android 5.0 Nexus 5

Tags: java, android, permissions, adb, file-transfer

Workflow:
1)I copy directory from PC via ADB tool on Nexus 5 in /data/local/tmp/ and set full permissions chmod (777) and owner is shell. There are files in it.

2)I want to rename(efficiently copy) this directory in App's directory /data/data/app.id/files/ using java method file rename. It was working with Android 4.4.4 but not working on 5.0 - permissions denied.

Any ideas how to solve this? 
Alternative workflow or any way to chown(problem is I do not known app user since files are created before the app is installed)? 
I do not want to copy files since this will duplicate content and is slow.

Comment: The problem may be that you cannot modify the /data/local/tmp directory itself (by moving the file out of it).  Instead of /data/local/tmp/yourfolder try creating /data/local/tmp/container and granting rwx permission to that, and then creating /data/local/tmp/container/yourfolder to hold your files.  The app can then mv yourfolder from container to somewhere else, and only need to modify container but not /data/local/tmp itself.  That said, this sounds like a very hack-y way to deploy data to a device.

Comment: Actually I am doing exactly that, the ADB writes to /data/local/tmp/specialdir/the-data-dir/ and the App searches for the the-data-dir and copies it using file rename API and this was working on android 4.4.4 but something has changed in 5.0. I am thinking of chown from ADB when the app is installed, this should allow rename to work.. This deploys files data from PC to app on device fast.